# jQuery exclude specific TD on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to exclude a specific `TD` (like the first one) from the `row` event of jQuery that I created below?

```js
jQuery("#list tbody tr").click(function(){
alert('click this');
//some code here
});

jQuery("#list tbody tr td.exclude").click(function(){
alert('click not that');
//some code here
});
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="list">
    <tr>
        <td class="exclude">first</td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="exclude">first</td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>third</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to be able to have an event for my `row` but exclude from all `TD` with class `exclude`, is that possible?

Comment: You can add a class to all wanted TD like class="wantClick" and then just update jQuery("td.wantClick")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `target` property on event object and check if it has class `exclude`.

```js
$('tr').click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target)
    .parents()
    .andSelf()
    .hasClass('exclude')) {
    alert('Click')
  }
})
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="list">
  <tr>
    <td class="exclude"><div><span>first</span></div></td>
    <td>second</td>
    <td>third</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="exclude">first</td>
    <td>second</td>
    <td>third</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the perfect solution for me!

Comment: You're welcome, note that it will remove click from any element that has class exclude not just td, so you can add this if you only want to remove it from td with exclude class https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2517/

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude an element using `not` method:

```
$('#list tr td').not('.exclude').on('click', function(e) {
    console.warn('click!');
});
```

Comment: The event is supposed to go onto the tr afais

Answer (score 2):

Try with `:not()` in the selector

```js
jQuery("#list tbody tr td:not(.exclude)").click(function(){
alert('click this');
//some code here
});
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="list">
    <tr>
        <td class="exclude">first</td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="exclude">first</td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>third</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [:not](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) selector in your jQuery so it would look something like this:

```
jQuery("#list tbody tr td:not(.exclude)").click(function(){
  alert('click this');
  //some code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:not` css selector just like that in one call:

```
jQuery("#list tbody tr td:not(.exclude)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will get your goal...

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#list tr').click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('exclude')) {
    alert('Click')
  }
})
```

});